# Elastic search partial match but strict phrase matching

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to fuzzy partial match against a field where the words match, however I want to also add in strict phrase matching.

i.e. say I have fields such as

```
foo bar
bar foo
```

I would like to achieve the following search behaviour:

- If I search `foo`, I would like to return back both results.
- If I search `ba`, I would like to return back both results.
- If I search `bar foo`, I would like to only return back one result.
- If I search `bar foo foo`, I don't want to return any results.

I would also like to add in single character fuzziness matching, so if a `foo` is mistyped as `fbo` then it would return back both results.

My current search and index analyzer uses an `edge_gram` tokenizer and is working fairly well, except if any gram matches, it will return the results regardless if the following words match. i.e. my search would return the back the following result for the search `bar foo buzz`

```
foo bar
bar foo
```

My tokenzier:

```
ngram_tokenizer: {
   type: "edge_ngram",
   min_gram: "2",
   max_gram: "15",
   token_chars: ['letter', 'digit', 'punctuation', 'symbol'],
},
```

My analyzer:

```
nGram_analyzer: {
  filter: [
  lowercase,
    "asciifolding"
  ],
  type: "custom",
  tokenizer: "ngram_tokenizer"
},
```

My field mapping:

```
type: "search_as_you_type",
doc_values: false,
max_shingle_size: 3,
analyzer: "nGram_analyzer"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve all your requirements is to use [span_near](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-near-query.html) query

**Span near query are much longer, but these are suitable for doing phrase match along with fuzziness parameter**

Adding a working example with index data, search queries and search results

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "title":"bar foo"
}
{
    "title":"foo bar"
}
```

**Search Queries:**

> If I search `foo`, I would like to return back both results.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "span_near": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "title": {
                        "value": "foo",
                        "fuzziness": 2
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "slop": 0,
            "in_order": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67205552",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "title": "bar foo"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67205552",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "title": "foo bar"
        }
      }
    ]
```

> If I search `ba`, I would like to return back both results.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "span_near": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "title": {
                        "value": "ba",
                        "fuzziness": 2
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "slop": 0,
            "in_order": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67205552",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "title": "bar foo"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67205552",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "title": "foo bar"
        }
      }
    ]
```

> If I search `bar foo foo`, I don't want to return any results.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "span_near": {
            "clauses": [
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "title": {
                        "value": "bar",
                        "fuzziness": 2
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "title": {
                        "value": "foo",
                        "fuzziness": 2
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "span_multi": {
                  "match": {
                    "fuzzy": {
                      "title": {
                        "value": "foo",
                        "fuzziness": 2
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "slop": 0,
            "in_order": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result will be empty**

Comment: Hi ESCoder thank you for your in-depth review. Is it possible to achieve the intended result without having to split each word into its own "span_multi" match query? i.e `bar foo foo` would be a single query rather than a composite span_multi queries?

Comment: @ErrolGreen As far as I know, I don't think there is any other way apart from using span queries, to achieve phrase matching with fuzziness

Comment: If I were to drop the fuzziness requirement would there be a solution that would only require a single clause?

Comment: @ErrolGreen no still there will not be any other way, as you need strict phrase matching also.

Comment: @ErrolGreen it's true that span queries are a little verbose, but based on your requirements, only this is applicable. I tried every other possible way, but couldn't figure out any other way.